# How to do sqlplus in bash if else?

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, sqlplus

I am trying to write a bash function which should delete some entries from table1 if the user enters 1, otherwise remove different entries. My function looks like this:

```
function reset_db
{
        if [ $usr_input == 1 ]  
        then
        sqlplus -s $USR/$pwd@$SID << EOF

        delete from table1 where component = 'ABC';
        delete from table2 where component = 'ABC';
        exit
EOF
        else if [ $usr_input == 2 ]

        delete from table1 where component = 'XYZ';
        delete from table2 where component = 'XYZ';
        exit
EOF
fi
}
```

I am getting error: *syntax error near unexpected token `fi'*

I am sure that it is happening because I am using if-else incorrectly somewhere but not able to figure out a way to fix it.

Also please let me know how can I post code under the same thread if I have any more follow up questions.

Comment: Please don't use "Thanks" in your questions. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the command in each clause of the `if` statement:

```
function reset_db
{
        if [ $usr_input == 1 ]  
        then
        sqlplus -s $USR/$pwd@$SID << EOF

        delete from table1 where component = 'ABC';
        delete from table2 where component = 'ABC';
        exit
EOF
        elif [ $usr_input == 2 ]; then

        sqlplus -s $USR/$pwd@$SID << EOF
        delete from table1 where component = 'XYZ';
        delete from table2 where component = 'XYZ';
        exit
EOF
fi
}
```

As a simplification, you should refactor this:

```
reset_db () {
    if [[ $usr_input = 1 ]]; then
      to_delete='ABC'
    elif [[ $usr_input = 2 ]]; then
      to_delete='XYZ'
    else
      return
    fi
    sqlplus -s "$USR/$pwd@$SID" <<EOF
    delete from table1 where component = '$to_delete'
    delete from table2 where component = '$to_delete'  
    exit
EOF
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful to have a precise code. But I have some schemas which end with 'ABC'. Ex: read_ABC, write_ABC, execute_ABC. If I give something like: `delete from table1 where component = '%\_$to_delete' ` then I am getting "invalid character" error. How can I do this?

Comment: It is pointing the error at "%".

`delete from upgrade_details where component = %_'ABC'
                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character`

Comment: It would be better to use bind variable.

Comment: It is fixed. There was a typo. Also I used "like" to do the string match.

Comment: 1. I want to prompt user for the owner name and read in a variable called owner
` read -p "Enter schema owner: " owner
2. Now I want to pass this value to this block of sql:
`declare
 usr2kill varchar2(5) := '&owner';
 sqlstmt varchar2(10);
......some more code to delete the users...`

My code looks like this:

`function reset_db
{
read -p "Enter Schema Owner: " owner

declare
        usr2kill varchar2(5) := '&owner';
        sqlstmt varchar2(10);
begin
......some more code to drop the users...`

Please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your original question has been answered. Please open a new question for further improvements, if only because comments are a poor place to post code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have posted a new question now.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'else if' is wrong, the correct syntax is 'elif'.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Actually I do programming in Java and now I am learning bash (which is going to be my scripting language). So I am having hard time with syntax. Anyways thanks again.